# Plugin for Android Marketplace downloads?

Tags: plugin-development, plugins

Is anyone aware of any way to show statistics on your WP blog to show android market place downloads?

For example, I create an application and host it on the android market place, it gets downloaded/installed 10 times. Is there any plugin I can use to display these figures/links etc on the sidebar in WP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/android-application-widget/) will display information from the Android Market, it may be able to be modified to include statistics, but I'm not sure.

Otherwise, there are no existing plugins that do what you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

I've posed that question to Developer Support and I'm waiting on an answer, but in the meantime, they do have guidelines for advertising the plugin, so you can begin building ads/banners, whatever.

I'd suggest that you ask the metrics question to Google with an open ticket in Android Market [here](http://www.google.com/support/androidmarket/bin/request.py?contact_type=publisher)